# How to Hide of Fragments In android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am Using Fragments For my app. My xml file looks like this

```
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_weight="1">
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="2">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     class="com.org.nyaya.ListFragment"  />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
</LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Have Listfragment and Detail fragment. Wat i want to do is There is a Button in detail Fragment. when i click that button I need to call newFragment and HIDE ListFragment and again in NewFragment when i click back I need to show ListFragment. Thanks for any help.

Edited

I Have Image here

[image]

Comment: why not to use fragmentTransaction.replace()?

Comment: @VitaliyErmakov When i use  fragmentTransaction.replace() only deatil fragment is replacing with newFeagment. List fragment remains same. I need to hide That ListFragment

Comment: @nikis newFragment is nothing But a fragment Thats it

Comment: @user2199280 Because your `ListFragment` is declared in XML. `FragmentManager` is not working with fragments in XML. You can declare containers in your XML for fragments and work with them dynamically. Does it make sense?